# nrpe: Host is not allowed to talk to us

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I installed nrpe on new servers. Nagios is already running and checking other server (I haven't installed).

I've got several error lines in my syslog file :

```
Oct 31 15:17:01 myservername nrpe[41848]: Host nagios_ip is not allowed to talk to us!
```

My nrpe.cfg file includes the following line :

```
allowed_hosts=nagios_ip
```

What am I doing wrong ?

(with nagios_ip the actual IP for my nagios server)

Comment: Have you tried restarting the nrpe service on the target server?

Comment: Yes I did but it had no effect

Comment: Which OS and Nagios/NRPE version is installed?

Comment: Also. Check nrpe.conf for whitespaces after allowed_hosts=<ip>.

In vim 

        :set list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same entry in my `syslog`.
Editing `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` and enter missing IP will fixed it at all.

```
allowed_hosts=1.2.3.4/24,127.0.0.1
```

After editing you have to restart or even reload `nrpe` deamon.

```
/etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server reload
```

Check if it is all fine with your configuration. Syslog should have an entry like this:

```
Allowing connections from: 1.2.3.4/24,127.0.0.1
```

I advise you not to add user nagios to sudoers because of security issues.

Comment: "I advise you not to add user nagios to sudoers because of security issues." Could you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of how-to's here and there ask you to allow your monitoring server IP like this in your host's `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` :

```
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1, 1.2.3.4
```

On some distribs (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for instance), it's working.
On other (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - tested on Microsoft Azure in my case), it does not.

Just remove the space before second IP :

```
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,1.2.3.4
```

Then, of course, restart your host's nrpe service :

```
$ service nagios-nrpe-server restart
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, but the error message is totally misleading. The user nagios has to be in the suders...

/etc/sudoers:

```
nagios  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/
```

Comment: this is not correct at all, actually

Comment: well, this solved the problem at once. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: One should definitely not do this. The nagios user should not have super permissions. Use the answer from @JaMaBing

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to add nagios to your sudoers file. If you're nagios server is in `allowed_hosts` but you're still getting this error, the following work flow will probably fix it (at least it did with mine):

`sudo@host: ls -l /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/` if any are `-rwxr-x-r-x` then

`sudo@host: chmod 777 /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/*
 sudo@host: /etc/init.d/nagios-nrpe-server reload`

then to check, do on your nagios server

`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H <server>`

Good Luck!

Comment: `chmod 777` is a quite bad advice; making all the files world write-/read-/executable? Really...?

Comment: "You do not want to add nagios to your sudoers file." Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: you're making these perl/python/bash scripts that check system information rwx by everyone instead of giving **sudo** access to a user. If you don't understand how sudo works, or what it is I encourage you to google it. if you're worried about it, `chmod 755`

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I'm appreciating your hints...good to see, that _you_ are in fact quite clueless what's possible with `sudo`, and how to limit access. Just giving a user access to `sudo` doesn't mean anything, in contrast to your `chmod 777`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem myself.  The way I fixed it was to remove all of the whitespace from the allowed_hosts line.  This is on nrpe 2.12 that's shipping on ubuntu 12.04.  There is some documentation that indicated you should use ', ' for the field delimiter, however that does not appear to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. However, this was previously working fine. there is no whitespace in my allowed_hosts line. However when I run `systemctl status nrpe` it shows that it is only allowing connections from 127.0.0.1.,::1 Issue only started recently

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/527445)